# Find indexof array of objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexof

When working with an array of values, `indexof` can be used to find the position of the value in the array.

```
#this returns '1', correctly identifying 'blue' in position '1' of the array
$valueArray = @('cup','blue','orange','bicycle')
[array]::indexof($valueArray,'blue')
```

I would like to use this command to find the position of a file (image) in an array of objects generated with `Get-ChildItem`, however the returned position is always '-1' no matter where the object I have called for actually is. Note that image123.jpg is in the middle of the array.

```
$imageArray = Get-ChildItem "C:\Images"
[array]::indexof($imageArray,'image123.jpg')
```

I have noticed that if I change the array to filenames only, it works returning the actual position of the filename.

```
$imageArray = Get-ChildItem "C:\Images" | select -expand Name
[array]::indexof($imagesToReview,'image123.jpg')
```

Is this just the nature of using `indexof` or is there a way to find the correct position of the image file in the array without converting?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` returns an array of `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` objects. Those objects contains various properties and values. You have better results when you select only the value of the name property because that is a string that contains the file name. If you used `[array]::indexof($imageArray.Name,'image123.jpg')` in your first example, you would have better results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest solution here is the following:

```
$imageArray = Get-ChildItem "C:\Images"
[array]::indexof($imageArray.Name,'image123.jpg')
```

**Explanation:**

`[array]::IndexOf(array array,System.Object value)` searches an `array` object for an object `value`. If no match is found, it returns the `array` lower bound minus 1. Since the array's first index is `0`, then it returns the result of `0-1`.

`Get-ChildItem -Path SomePath` returns an array of `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` objects. Each of those objects has various properties and values. Just using `$imageArray` to compare to `image123.jpg` would be comparing a `System.IO.FileInfo` object to a `String` object. PowerShell won't automatically convert a `FileInfo` object into a string while correctly parsing to find your target value.

When you choose to select a property value of each object in the array, you are returning an array of those property values only. Using `$imageArray | Select -Expand Name` and `$imageArray.Name` return an array of `Name` property values. `Name` contains a string in your example. This means you are comparing a `String` to a `String` when using `[array]::IndexOf($imageArray.Name,'image123.jpg')`.

Answer (score 3):

The way that .NET by default **compares** things is just not as *forgiving* as PowerShell is!

`[array]::IndexOf($array, $reference)` will go through the array and return the current index when it encounters an item for which the following is true:

```
$item.Equals($reference)
```

... which is **NOT *necessarily*** the same as doing

```
$item -eq $reference
```

---

For simple values, like numbers and dates and so on, `Equals()` works exactly like `-eq`:

```
PS C:\> $a = 1
PS C:\> $b = 1
PS C:\> $a.Equals($b)  # $true
```

... which is the reason your first example works as expected!

For more complex objects though, `Equals()` works a bit differently. Both values MUST refer to the ***same*** object, it's not enough that they have similar or even identical values:

```
PS C:\> $a = New-Object object
PS C:\> $b = New-Object object
PS C:\> $a.Equals($b)    # $false
```

In the example above, `$a` and `$b` are similar (if not *identical*) - they're both empty objects - but they are not *the same object*.

Similarly, if we test with your input values, they aren't *the same* either:

```
PS C:\> $a = Get-Item "C:\"
PS C:\> $b = "C:\"
PS C:\> $a.Equals($b)    # $false
```

One of the reasons they can't be considered the same, as [AdminOfThings excellently explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61348175/712649), is *type mismatch* - but PowerShell's comparison operators can help us here!

You'll notice that *this* works:

```
PS C:\> $a = Get-Item "C:\"
PS C:\> $b = "C:\"
PS C:\> $b -eq $a
True
```

That's because the behavior of `-eq` depends on the left-hand operand. In the example above, `"C:\"` is a string, so PowerShell converts `$a` to a string, and all of a sudden the comparison is more like `"C:\".Equals("C:\")`!

With this in mind, you could create your own `Find-IndexOf` function to do `$reference -eq $item` (or any other comparison mechanism you'd like) with a simple `for()` loop:

```bsh
function Find-IndexOf
{
  param(
    [array]$Array,
    [object]$Value
  )

  for($idx = 0; $idx -lt $Array.Length; $idx++){
    if($Value -eq $Array[$idx]){
      return $idx
    }
  }

  return -1
}
```

Now you'd be able to do:

```
PS C:\> $array = @('','PowerShell is case-insensitive by default')
PS C:\> $value = 'POWERsheLL iS cASe-InSenSItIVe BY deFAuLt'
PS C:\> Find-IndexOf -Array $array -Value $value
1
```

Or:

```
PS C:\> $array = Get-ChildItem C:\images
PS C:\> $value = 'C:\images\image123.png'
PS C:\> Find-IndexOf -Array $array -Value $value
5
```

Adding comparison against a specific property on each of the array items (like the file's `Name` in your example), we end up with something like this:

```bsh
function Find-IndexOf
{
  param(
    [array]$Array,
    [object]$Value,
    [string]$Property
  )

  if($Property){
    for($idx = 0; $idx -lt $Array.Length; $idx++){
      if($Value -eq $Array[$idx].$Property){
        return $idx
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for($idx = 0; $idx -lt $Array.Length; $idx++){
      if($Value -eq $Array[$idx]){
        return $idx
      }
    }
  }

  return -1
}

Find-IndexOf -Array @(Get-ChildItem C:\images) -Value image123.png -Property Name
```

Comment: This is truly above and beyond, thanks so much for the detail to the solution.